# Entity Framework 6 How to make a subquery

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, subquery

code:

```
    int companiesId = context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == UserId).Select(x => x.Companies.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    
    
  tasksList1 = context.Tasks.Where(x => x.User.Companies.Id == companiesId).Include(x => x.User).ThenInclude(x => x.Companies).Include(x => x.Documents).Select(x => new ListTaskViewModel
                    {
                        Assigned = x.User.Name,
                        Constituent = context.Users.Where(c => c.Id == x.Constituent).Select(v => v.Name).FirstOrDefault().ToString() //here is actually the user id. I need to fetch user's name with user id ,
                        Title = x.Title,
                        Description = x.Description,
                        Priority = x.Priority,
                        Urgency = x.Urgency,
                        CompletionTime = x.CompletionTime,
                        DocumentViewModels = x.Documents.ToList()
                    }).ToList();
```

"Constituent" a user id. I'm trying to reach the user's name with that user id. but it gives an error like below:

error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

I need to subquery to the "constructor" the user's name, not the id. how can I do it?

Comment: Would be great if you can provide the complete exception details. This `.FirstOrDefault().ToString()` may lead to the issue for the case that when `FirstOrDeefault` returns `null`. Think that the `.ToString()` is not needed as the `context.Users.Where(...).Select(v => v.Name).FirstOrDefault()` would return a `string` or `null` value.

Comment: @YongShun I just typed "first" and this time such an error came.  System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements.'

Comment: For `.First()`, it must be required to return a value from the sequence. If there is possible that no value is returned from the sequence, you shall use `.FirstOrDefault()`. Just my concern is **not to use `.ToString()` after `.FirstOrDefault()`**, as the code will break down when `.FirstOrDefault()` returns `null`.

Comment: @YongShun yes I deleted "tostring()" and the data came back null. but in reality they are not null. why is it null? data is wrong.

Comment: @YongShun yes both int. "c.id" is the id in the users table. If "Constituent" is the user id in the task table

Comment: @YongShun Where(c => c.Id == x.Constituent && x.User.Companies.Id == companiesId)   doing the condition like this fixed it. thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of sub query

```
from u in Users
join c in CompanyRolesToUsers 
on u.Id equals c.UserId
where u.LastName.Contains("fra") &&
selectedRoles.Contains(c.CompanyRoleId)
select u
```